# How to protect my EXE resources?

Tags: c#, resources, exe

My problem is that i wanna include EXE file with my C# project as a resource  and i found the method below on the internet and it works perfectly except that after i run it ,The EXE file gets extracted to the hard drive and i wanna keep it hidden from the person who will run my C# software , I used  File.Delete() to get ride of the file when its closed but it can be copied to other places on the hard drive after you start it from the C# project , So is there anyway to protect the EXE file from getting copied? Like locking it or at least hiding it? Also if its possible to read the file without the need to extract  it that would be great , I would appreciate it if you guys be specific because I'm new to C# programming , Thanks .

```
byte[] exeBytes = Properties.Resources.MyTestExe;
string exeToRun = @"Resources.MyTestExe.exe";

using (FileStream exeFile = new FileStream(exeToRun, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    exeFile.Write(exeBytes, 0, exeBytes.Length);
}

using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(exeToRun))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    File.Delete(exeToRun);
}
```

Comment: This just seems fishy to me.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

> So is there anyway to protect the EXE file from getting copied?

No, there is absolutely, positively, no way to do this. You can make it harder by encrypting the content of the file in one way or another, but a sufficiently determined user with a debugger would always be able to break your protection.

Also note that the practice of writing out an EXE and then executing it would be highly suspicious from the point of view of most, if not all, active anti-virus protection mechanisms. You would be better off re-thinking the way of providing the functionality that is currently provided by writing and executing an EXE file.